# Cannot style elements using DOM manipulation when new class is added by element.classList.add() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to style a table like this

```
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td >Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which has a Javascript code that would create classes shown below

```
td.classList.add("col");
```

However I don't understand why styling using that class won't work with the below code

```
const tabl= document.getElementsByClassName("col");

    for (var i = 0; i < tabl.length; i++) {
      tabl[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
```

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for anybody to diagnose the problem. If your code actually does add the class to some `<td>` elements, then the code would work.

Comment: When you say "*styling using that class won't work*" what exactly do you mean? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Can you supply a [mcve] that demonstrates what you observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can't see where you're going wrong from the little code you presented.  I filled in the gaps as best I could to get this working, and it adds the red color for me.

```
//Get NodeList of all tds
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

//Convert NodeList to Array
tds = Array.from(tds);

//Add class 'col' to each td
tds.map((td) => td.classList.add('col'));

//Get all '.col' elements
const tabl= document.getElementsByClassName("col");

//Programmatically set style attribute on each .col
for (var i = 0; i < tabl.length; i++) {
  tabl[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

It's generally considered bad practice to directly, programmatically set the style of an element in this way; it's better to add a class and handle style via the CSS file.  Since you're already adding a class, why not just set that class to set background-color: red in the CSS file anyway?

Anyway, you can check a StackBlitz here to see it up and running: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2zm68n

Comment: hey Thomas preston so we always need to convert NodeList to array for traversing or manipulating it ? I thought we could directly manipulate it. Is this why my code didn't work?

Comment: No, you do not always need to convert the NodeList to an Array.  I only did that here because I wanted to use .map, which is not available on NodeList.  You could achieve a similar effect with a basic for loop on the elements in the NodeList.  Without seeing more of your code I can't say for sure, but I have a feeling you're calling td.classList.add() on the Node List, rather than on the individual nodes, in which case you're not setting the col class on anything.  I'd have to see how you're accessing td in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why use class name? Please try this. Hope it can help

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
var tds = Array.from(elements)
tds.map(element => {
  element.setAttribute('class', 'classname')
})

// check
console.log('finded tds: ' + document.getElementsByClassName('classname').length)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td >Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Mohammed Abedi I know this does but I specifically need to know why using the classList.add() method doesn't work

Comment: Why not use set attribute? element.setAttribute('class', 'yourclass')

Comment: @VLAZ it doesn't set the background color of all <td> elements red. I'm guessing it's not adding the class but I don't know how else to use the method.

Comment: @stealth225 OK, so *how* are you currently trying to do this?

Comment: let me what filter you want to do?

Comment: @VLAZ So after i wrote the html, I'm trying to add the class name dynamically using the classList.add method , then I try to query the Dom using that new class, also in JS. The code is pasted above in my question.

Comment: Yes you wrote the code but the code you sent is incomplete. My question is which TDs do you want to add to the class?

Comment: Mohammad Abedi all the tds